# Less formal synonyms for "barred"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

> Nobody but guards on duty were allowed inside the building itself and outsiders were *blank* from the compound altogether.

The only words I can think of for *blank* are *barred* or *forbidden to enter* both of which sound a little too formal. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...outsides were *blocked from entering* the compound altogether.

Answer (score 3):

...outsiders were *excluded* from the compound...

Answer (score 1):

Restricted. Prohibited.  A less formal construction might be, "Outsiders couldn't even get onto the compound, let alone into the building, where only guards on duty were allowed."

Comment: I was going to comment against OP that I didn't really think *barred* was particularly formal anyway, but I can't deny this alternative has a much more informal tone.

Answer (score 1):

- 'prevented' - "They were prevented from entering the building" (a little bit formal)
- 'kept' - "They were kept from entering the building" (very straightforward, not formal, not particularly informal, very plain though)
- 'stopped from entering' - also very plain. (implies though a little bit more active intervention maybe as opposed to just say a fence)